# Reduce space between two Unicode characters in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, unicode, nsstring

I need to show two Unicode characters in a string i.e. superscript. I am doing that like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u02e2\u00B9 2010"]);
```

And I am able to show that also, but my problem is that it's showing some space between these two characters. How can I reduce this space?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no space between the 2 character, but just before "2010" --->  "ˢ¹ 2010"

it's not clear if you want the space or not...

if you want it just use:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u02e2 \u00B9 2010"]);
```

Comment: yes, i guessed that, but it wasn't clear if he had the space but didn't want it (but in log i have no space) or if he had no space and he wanted it (and as he accepted my answer now i guess this second option is the right one, but that's not what he asked in his question... may be some english problem...)